# BTree Complexity based on M and L and based on order of insertion and deletion

Tags: tree, big-o, complexity-theory, abstract, b-tree

What are the big Oh for BTree that depends on M = the number of keys and L = the number of leaves?

How does BTree deal with deleting in order and in reverse order?

I am doing an analysis on how the M and L and the way things are inserted and deleted in BTree determines the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

B-trees remain perfectly balanced at all times, so deleting in reverse order will be the same as deleting in-order, and will always start at the same level (the deepest level).

Depending on the B-tree implementation, operations will occur in O(log(m) * log(l)) time or O(m * log(l)) time. The latter is for known small m values, because binary searching inside an array of 5 or so elements is not really worth it.